# Submit form after countdown finishes

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to submit the document (`return_url`) only after the countdown finishes. In my current code below the document is submitted just after the countdown starts. How can I make the countdown finish before submitting the `document_url`?

**Code:**

```
<body>
    <center>
        <form name="redirect"><font face="Helvetica"><b>
            Thank you! You will be redirected in<input type="text" size="1" style="font-size:25px" name="redirect2">seconds.</b></font>
        </form></form>
    </center>

    <form name="return_url" method="post" action="confirm.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="order" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="100" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var targetURL="<?php print_r($_POST['url_retorno']);?>"
    var countdownfrom=10
    var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1

    function countredirect(){
        if (currentsecond!=1){
            currentsecond-=1
            document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond
        } else {
            window.location=targetURL
            return
        }
        setTimeout("countredirect()",1000)
    }

    countredirect()

    document.return_url.submit()    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Big point, you shouldn't automatically submit forms for users, it's kind of a bad UX design. Instead, you could do the wait before submiting thing which disables the button until the timer is up. And for that, you just need to make use of javascript timers.

```
var timer = window.setInterval(updateClock,1000);
var countdown = 10;
function updateClock() {
   countdown--;
   if(countdown<=0) {
       window.clearInterval(timer);
       //ALLOW THE FORM TO SUBMIT
       document.getElementById("elementID").disabled = false
   } else {
       document.getElementById("elementID").value = "PLEASE WAIT "+countdown+" SECONDS";
   }
}
```

I'm also adding in a side point that you should never trust what people put into forms. Lookup XSS or cross site scripting, and SQL injection to find out why. So you need to use validation (even for numbers). If you want on page validation (which still isn't really secure since it can be by-passed) you could add a `onSubmit="validate()"` attribute to the form tag to call the `validate()` function when the user does finally submit it. Using this function also gives you the power to take over the form if needed, since you can execute any javascript you want there and simply returning a "false" value will cause the form to NOT submit.

**ALWAYS VALIDATE YOUR FORM ENTRIES ON THE SERVER LEVEL (ie. in the confirm.php file)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {document.return_url.submit();}, 10000);
```

That should be all you need.

Or if you want to display the timer, use setInterval();

```
var seconds_left = 10;
var timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    seconds_left--;
    if (seconds_left) {
        console.log(seconds_left); //or modify the DOM
    } else {
        document.return_url.submit();
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you just use `window.setTimeout(countredirect, 10000);` ?

Comment: Also, I didn't read the question clearly enough.  Your answer is much more complete.

Comment: Thank you, you actually accomplished what they where doing easier though.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the OP also wanted to display a countdown.

Comment: For my case this option is the best. But the problem is if i replace
document.return_url.submit() with setTimeout(function() {document.return_url.submit();}, 10000);
The submit goes empty (doesn't send the form input values).

Comment: Hmmm... that's very odd.

Comment: Simply typing document.return_url.submit() into the console works, though?

Comment: Maybe because in my production code i have php code inside the form. Could it be the problem? 
See the code:
 `<input type="hidden" name="order" value="<?php print_r($_POST['orderID']);?>" />`

Comment: The info is being posted and it works ok if i use `document.return_url.submit()`. But it goes empty if i use your suggestion.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem.  The PHP code will have already been executed by the time the javascript begins to execute.  Do you get an empty JSON object, or empty values? 

In other words, {} or {key1: "", key2: ""}?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at it.  I'm working on a JSFiddle for the issue at the moment, and I'll be right back with you in a few minutes.

Comment: start a chat conversation

Comment: No problem.  Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the issue, though.  I used a bit of jQuery to show you what values are passed via the POST when the form is submitted.  Check it out in the dev console of your browser at http://jsfiddle.net/YcSh7/8/

Comment: I see. And Is it possible to do the submit using jquery?

Comment: It is.  Try $('form[name="return_url"]').submit().  I don't expect that to change anything though.